# update_user_meta doesn't work with AJAX

Tags: ajax, user-meta

I try to keep user subscription in a metadata var.
The function is called by AJAX. Ahe AJAX is called but the metadata does not seem updated on frontend.

Here is the code:

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#tags_list a').click(function(){
            myid = $(this).parent("li").attr('id');
            $.post(
                '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>', 
                {
                    'action': 'change_subscription',
                    'type': 'post_tag',
                    'term_id': myid
                }, 
                function(response){
                    $('#'+myid).toggleClass('checked');
                }
            );
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

AJAX

```
add_action('wp_ajax_change_subscription', 'change_subscription');
function change_subscription() {
if (!empty($_POST['term_id']) && !empty($_POST['type'])) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'hannit_meta', 'My Value' );
    die();
} else
    die($st);
}
```

Front-end check:

```
<?php
            $user = wp_get_current_user()->ID;
            $tags = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'hannit_meta', true);
            echo "<!-- u:".$user." val ".$tags."-->";
            ?>
```

Result: `<!-- u:236 val-->`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

First You can get rid of nasty globals in your AJAX call.  I'm not sure what the `$st` variable that you were output is all about so I've excluded, but you can include as you wish -

```
add_action('wp_ajax_change_subscription', 'change_subscription');
function change_subscription(){

    if(!empty($_POST['term_id']) && !empty($_POST['type'])) :

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();       
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'hannit_meta', 'My Value' );

    endif;

    die();

}
```

For testing, it looks like you were querying the meta incorrectly, so pleaes try this -

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$tags = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'hannit_meta', true);
echo "<!-- u:".$user_id." val ".$tags."-->";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this exact method myself and was curious as to why your code wouldn't work. I changed two things; it may be one or both of them that fixed it.

Firstly, you seem to be missing a bracket after your `else` in the `change_subscription` function. Secondly; I usually err on the side of caution and use the global `$current_user` object:

```
function change_subscription() {
    if (!empty($_POST['term_id']) && !empty($_POST['type'])) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'hannit_meta', 'My Value');

        die();
    } else {
        die();
    }
}
```

You also had an `$st` variable in your second `die()` - I don't know if this was defined elsewhere, but I omitted it for the sake of neatness. Depending on the strictness of your setup, an undefined variable may throw a spanner in the works.

Anyway, using this exact code, this works perfectly for me. And thanks for the jumping-off point - I used your code as the basis for my own similar AJAX function.

Comment: You've used `$user->ID` but where are you getting the `$user` object?

Comment: @henrywright Code typo - updated.

Comment: If you just want the current user's ID, you could probably just do `get_current_user_id()` and get rid of the global

Comment: @henrywright Probably. There was no explanation as to why OP's code wasn't working (nor any follow-up or acceptance of this as a solution); I simply suggested a way that probably should (and *did*) work in my test.

Comment: Sure thing! Strange things happen during an AJAX call... :)